# What is the maximum and minimum height of each breed of Minecraft tree?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently making a universal tree farm in Minecraft, and I need to know the maximum and minimum height of each breed of tree, except for Dark Oak, and the large variations of some trees. Even though some trees (such as spruce) very rarely reach max height, because their tallest form is a rare almost toothpick-like tree, but I don't want to limit the height of the tree, as that still wastes some bonemeal, and I want efficiency to be max.

So what is the Minimum and Maximum height the each breed of Minecraft tree (Oak, Spruce, Jungle, etc) can reach?

Comment: The wiki answers this: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tree#Structure
If you had typed in the exact title of your question into Google, that would have been the first result. We expect a bit of effort here before asking questions, see the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I meant the minimum and the maximum of _each_ tree, meaning like a list of the highest and smallest a spruce tree can get, the highest and smallest an acacia tree can get, the highest and smallest an oak tree can get, etc. I thought I clarified enough in the description, sorry. @FabianRöling

Comment: Ah, ok. If you edit your question, I can undo my downvote. The wiki has some infos about different tree type heights, but not really a full list.

Comment: Not sure if that applies for all breeds, but the standard sizes are between 4 and 8 blocks with the bigger ones going up to 16 blocks and the large ones up to 32... magically all a power of 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been testing the maximum possible tree dimensions for each tree type and have come up with the following results (keep in mind these measurements include all possible leaf blocks and branches):

- **Big Jungle**: 16x16 width, 32 height
- **Regular Jungle**: 5x5 width, 13 height
- **Big Spruce**: 10x10 width, 30 height (note: these also turn some grass in a possible 12x12 area into podzol)
- **Regular Spruce**: 7x7 width, 10 height (matchstick style regular spruce
  trees cannot be grown with saplings)
- **Big Oak**: 13x13? width, 19? height (big oak
  trees are hard to test so this could be slightly off, also, big oak trees grow 1 leaf block taller if spawned naturally in a biome without the use of saplings)
- **Regular Oak**: 5x5 width, 7 height (somewhat redundant since there is
  always the possibility that a big oak will grow instead of a regular
  one)
- **Dark Oak**: 12x12 width, 11 height
- **Birch**: 5x5 width, 8 height (tall birch trees cannot be grown with
  saplings)
- **Acacia**: 12x12? width, 10 height (acacia trees are weird; when testing
  I never saw one with more than a 12x12 width, but it could be
  possible)
- [*Bonus*] **Chorus**: 11x11? width, 22 height (I didn't test this much myself, but instead got these results by researching online)

Answer (score 3):

Since a few new trees were added in the latest update, (current is 1.20.1 at time of writing,) I did some experiments with the new trees in case anyone finds it helpful:

- **Mangrove**: 15x15 width, 27 height (vines extend an extra block from each side)
- **Cherry**: 7x17 width, 11 height (may grow aligned either x or z)

And since I tested them anyway, the max sizes for each of the mushroom trees are:

- **Warped**: 7x7 width, 27? height
- **Crimson**: 7x7 width, 27? height
- **Brown**: 7x7 width, 11? height
- **Red**: 5x5 width, 11? height

The heights listed are the highest I found while testing, but may not be exact.